# Selecting the matching label to input on submit - autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am creating an autocomplete on one of my search inputs and have pretty much most of it working fine except one final part which is getting the system to recognise if the input matches a label if the label has not been clicked.

For example if 'London' is typed into the input box but the user does not click on the label for 'London' then the values of the label are not sent and it does not achieve the results that their are for london as the values are sent as null.

So what i want to achieve is that if london is typed into the input box but the label is not clicked then when the submit button is clicked the matching label for london is sent. This has to be for a direct match only so if "london" matches "london". How do i go about doing this?

here is my code so far :

html:

```
<div class="search-homepage-input">
    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'search.index', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-9 col-l">
    {!! Form::text('sl', null, array('class' => 'form-control shop-input', 'maxlength' =>'50', 'placeholder' => 'Search by city. Eg. London, New York, Paris...', 'id' => 'sl')) !!}
    </div>
    {!! Form::hidden('country', null, array('id' => 'country')) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('city', null, array('id' => 'city')) !!}
    <div class="col-md-3 col-r">
        {!! Form::submit('Find Shops', array('class' => 'btn btn-homepage-search'))  !!}
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

PHP laravel:

```
   public function autoComplete(Request $request){

        $query = $request->term;
        $res = City::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")->orderBy('name')->paginate(5);
        foreach($res as $cities ){
            $usersArray[] = array(
                "label" => $cities->name,
                "value" => $cities->id,
                "country" => $cities->countries->id,
                "countryname" => $cities->countries->country

            );
        }
        return response()->json($usersArray);
    }
```

JS:

```
 $('#sl').autocomplete({
    source: countries,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (ui.item.label === "No results found") {
        $("#sl").val("");
        return false;
      }
      $("#country").val(ui.item.country); // save selected id to hidden input
      $("#city").val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to hidden input
      $('#sl').val(ui.item.label + ', ' + ui.item.countryname)
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#sl').val(ui.item.label);
    },
    response: function(event, ui) {
      if (!ui.content.length) {
        var noResult = {
          value: "",
          label: 'No results found'
        };
        ui.content.push(noResult);
      }
    }
  });

  $("#sl").autocomplete("widget").menu("option", "items", "> li:not('.no-select')");

  $("#sl").autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    var li = $("<li>");
    if (item.country == undefined) {
      li.addClass("no-select").append(item.label);
    } else {
      li.append("<div><strong>" + item.label + "</strong>, " + item.countryname + "</div>");
    }
    return li.appendTo(ul);
  }
```

Comment: There is no feature like this in Autocomplete, please see: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ You would need to use `blur` event and issue a search to match the field value against a potential selection. Yet there is more than 1 result, you will encounter issues.

Comment: How would i go about doing that and using Blur? could you possibly give me help on that. Would it just be possible to pick the first exact match for example?